# MCSession is connecting, but never connected

Tags: ios, swift, mcsession

I have my simulator and phone seeing each other and the one acting as a browser inviting the advertiser into a session. However, the only 2 state changes I see on either side is .Connecting and .NotConnected. I never see .Connected.

Am I supposed to do something to go from .Connecting to .Connected on the advertiser or browser side? I don't see anything in the examples.

I do not have any disconnect statements in my code. Not sure why the connection is being broken.

Comment: This question and answer is not useful to others because both the question and answer reflect code that is unavailable to view.

Comment: @dwsolberg Exactly.. Having the same and not sure how to solve..

Comment: @Lapidus I wrote my own classes instead that work similarly.  https://github.com/AaronBratcher/ALBPeerConnection   (Need to swap out the socket class for one written in swift still)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ok I tested your source code and here is how I solved it.**

I replaced your varibale 'browserSession.session' with '_serverSession' and both the devices are connected properly and can send Data.

```
_browser?.invitePeer(device.peerID, toSession: _serverSession, withContext: data, timeout: timeoutTime)
```

Exclusive sessions are required for each peer to peer connection.
Enjoy.

Comment: I was hoping for a star topology where each browsing device could connect to multiple servers (1 session per server) and each server would have a single session to connect browsers to.