# MCSessionState changes from connecting to not connected state

Tags: swift, multipeer-connectivity, mcsession

Whenever I try to connect a peer using the [Multipeer Connectivity Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/), the peer's state changes from `MCSessionState.Connecting` to `MCSessionState.NotConnected`.

Here are the order of events I run:

1. The simulator advertises the service via an [MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MCNearbyServiceAdvertiserClassRef/index.html).
2. An iPhone browses for the service via an [MCNearbyServiceBrowser](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MCNearbyServiceBrowserClassRef/index.html).
3. The iPhone finds the simulator and immediately invites it to a
   session via [invitePeer(_:toSession:withContext:timeout:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MCNearbyServiceBrowserClassRef/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MCNearbyServiceBrowser/invitePeer:toSession:withContext:timeout:).
4. Finally, the simulator accepts the invitation using
   [advertiser(_:didReceiveInvitationFromPeer:withContext:invitationHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MCNearbyServiceAdvertiserDelegateProtocolRef/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MCNearbyServiceAdvertiserDelegate/advertiser:didReceiveInvitationFromPeer:withContext:invitationHandler:).

Notes:

- Even though I'm not requiring security, I'm accepting any certificates sent over by clients [in case that is the bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21281367/35690).

Here is the code I'm using:

```
import UIKit
import MultipeerConnectivity

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var advertiser: MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser!
    var browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser!
    var session: MCSession!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let localPeerID = MCPeerID(displayName: UIDevice.currentDevice().name)
        session = MCSession(peer: localPeerID, securityIdentity: nil, encryptionPreference: MCEncryptionPreference.None)
        session.delegate = self
    }

    @IBAction func hostTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        let localPeerID = MCPeerID(displayName: UIDevice.currentDevice().name)
        advertiser = MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser(peer: localPeerID, discoveryInfo: nil, serviceType: "abc")
        advertiser.delegate = self
        print("started advertising")
        advertiser.startAdvertisingPeer()
    }

    @IBAction func connectTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        let localPeerID = MCPeerID(displayName: UIDevice.currentDevice().name)
        browser = MCNearbyServiceBrowser(peer: localPeerID, serviceType: "abc")
        browser.delegate = self
        print("started searching")
        browser.startBrowsingForPeers()
    }
}

extension ViewController: MCNearbyServiceAdvertiserDelegate {
    func advertiser(advertiser: MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser, didReceiveInvitationFromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, withContext context: NSData?, invitationHandler: (Bool, MCSession) -> Void) {
        print("accepting invitation from \(peerID.displayName)")
        invitationHandler(true, session)
    }

    func advertiser(advertiser: MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser, didNotStartAdvertisingPeer error: NSError) {
        print("did not start advertising \(error)")
    }
}

extension ViewController: MCSessionDelegate {
    func session(session: MCSession, peer peerID: MCPeerID, didChangeState state: MCSessionState) {
        print("\(peerID.displayName) changed state: \(state.toString())")
    }

    func session(session: MCSession, didReceiveData data: NSData, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {

    }

    func session(session: MCSession, didReceiveStream stream: NSInputStream, withName streamName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {

    }

    func session(session: MCSession, didStartReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, withProgress progress: NSProgress) {

    }

    func session(session: MCSession, didFinishReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, atURL localURL: NSURL, withError error: NSError?) {

    }

    func session(session: MCSession, didReceiveCertificate certificate: [AnyObject]?, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, certificateHandler: (Bool) -> Void) {
        certificateHandler(true)
    }
}

extension ViewController: MCNearbyServiceBrowserDelegate {
    func browser(browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser, foundPeer peerID: MCPeerID, withDiscoveryInfo info: [String : String]?) {
        print("found \(peerID.displayName), inviting to session")
        browser.invitePeer(peerID, toSession: session, withContext: nil, timeout: 30)
    }

    func browser(browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser, lostPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
        print("lost \(peerID.displayName)")
    }
}

extension MCSessionState {
    func toString() -> String {
        switch self {
        case .Connected:    return "Connected"
        case .Connecting:   return "Connecting"
        case .NotConnected: return "Not Connected"
        }
    }
}
```

There is a similar [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28309070/35690), however, the code linked is old and can no longer be accessed. Furthermore, the problem was that the same session object was being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using different [MCPeerID](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MCPeerID_class/index.html) instances for the MCSession, MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser and MCNearbyServiceBrowser.

To fix it, I created an MCPeerID instance variable:

```
var localPeerID: MCPeerID?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    // ...
    localPeerID = MCPeerID(displayName: UIDevice.currentDevice().name)
    // ...
}
```

... and used it instead of creating them as local variables (`let localPeerID = ...`).

It now goes from the *connecting* to *connected* state correctly.

Comment: I was having the same issue. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Personally not a fan of force unwrapping in production code unless it really can't be helped. This could be made significantly safer by  setting it as a constant and initialising at the point of declaration or lazy loaded :)

Answer (score 1):

Can always just create it as a constant for the class!

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var advertiser: MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser!
    var browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser!
    var session: MCSession!

    let localPeerID = MCPeerID(displayName: UIDevice.currentDevice().name)
    ...
}
```